# контексты во flask

Tags: python, flask

Что такое контексты приложения и запроса?

Answer (score 6):

Flask использует контексты, чтобы временно делать определенные переменные доступными в глобальной области видимости. Они заставляют отдельные переменные вести себя как глобальные. Обращаясь к этим переменным, пользователь получает доступ к объекту в конкретном потоке. Технически такие переменные называются локальными или внутрипоточными.

Согласно документации Flask существует два вида контекстов:

- Контекст приложения
- Контекст запроса

Контекст приложения используется для хранения общих переменных приложения, таких как подключение к базе данных, настройки и т. д. А контекст запроса используется для хранения переменных конкретного запроса.

Контекст приложения предлагает такие объекты как `current_app` или `g`. `current_app` ссылается на экземпляр, который обрабатывает запрос, а `g` используется, чтобы временно хранить данные во время обработки запроса. Когда значение установлено, к нему можно получить доступ из любой функции представления. Данные в `g` сбрасываются после каждого запроса.

Как и контекст приложения, контекст запроса также предоставляет объекты: `request` и `session`. `request` содержит информацию о текущем запросе, а `session` — это словарь (dict). В нем хранятся значения, которые сохраняются между запросами.

Flask активирует контексты приложения и запроса, когда запрос получен и удаляет их, когда он обработан. Когда используется контекст приложения, все его переменные становятся доступным для потока. То же самое происходит и с контекстом запроса. Когда он активируется, его переменные могут быть использованы в потоке. Внутри функций представления можно получить доступ ко всем объектам контекстов приложения и запроса, так что не стоит волноваться о том, активны ли контексты или нет. Но если попробовать получить к ним доступ вне функции представления или в консоли Python, выйдет ошибка.

Чтобы получить доступ к объектам, предоставляемым контекстами приложения и запроса вне функции представления, нужно сперва создать соответствующий контекст.

Создать контекст приложения можно с помощью метода `app_context()` для экземпляра `Flask`.

```
from main import app
from flask import request, current_app


with app.app_context():
     current_app.name
```

При создании контекстов лучше всего использовать выражение `with`.

Похожим образом можно создавать контекст запроса с помощью метода `test_request_context()` в экземпляре Flask. Важно запомнить, что когда активируется контекст запроса, контекст приложения создается, если его не было до этого. Следующий код демонстрирует процесс создания контекста запроса:

```
from main import app
from flask import request, current_app

with app.test_request_context('/products'):
    request.path  # получим полный путь к запрашиваемой странице(без домена).
    request.method
    current_app.name
```

Адрес `/products` выбран произвольно.
Это все, что нужно знать о контекстах во Flask.

Взято отсюда - [Контексты во Flask](https://pythonru.com/uroki/4-konteksty-vo-flask#:%7E:text=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0.)